# html.tpl.php is deleted and the site is down!

Tags: theming, configuration

I'm [mid-versed in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/22728/mayeenul-islam), but newbie in Drupal, developing a Theme from scratch. I started with `page.tpl.php`, then extended the design with a custom front-page (`page--front.tpl.php`). Then for a custom structure I made `html.tpl.php`, after heard about it from a Drupal geek. But I found no connection with it to the site and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> it. And my site is down now.

To retrieve the site, I copied the `page.tpl.php` and renamed it to `html.tpl.php`. But till there is nothing but an alt text of my logo. I even can't get access to the `/user`, Clearing cache section. But cleared the browser cache with no hope.

Developing environment: WAMP 2.1, localhost

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. An unconventional solution though!

- **Step I:** I moved my custom theme from `sites/all/themes/` to one step up (`sites/all/`). So the system cannot identify the theme in place. I got access into the Drupal.
- **Step II:** I set "Bartik 7.22" as the Default theme.
- **Step III:** Then moved my theme back to its place again.
- **Step IV:** Renamed the file `html.tpl.php` to `html.tpl.php.BACKUP`.
- **Step V:** Then reactivated and set default my theme in the Appearance.

It's live!

> **Reason:** I think it's the Drupal cache. The process I followed was simply tweaking the caching in an alternative, but unconventional way.